# Django if statement is not working while comparing it with model values and html input

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-tagging

In results.html file I want to check if input value from html page and values from models are same. if so then show the matched result. But my code only executes else part.

This is my results.html

```
<div class="card-body bg-light">
   <h5>Your data :</h5>
   <p>Your pH value: {{ ph }} pH. </p>
   <p>Your moisture value: {{ moist }}</p>      
   <div style="color: white;">
        {% for g in crop_data %}
          {% if ph == g.ph and moist == g.moisture %}             
            <p>{{ g.name }}</p>
            <p>{{ g.ph }}</p>
            <p>{{ g.moisture }}</p>
          {% else %}
            <p>Sorry for your inconvience</p>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}            
  </div>     
</div>
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class cropInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    moisture = models.IntegerField()
    ph = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my views.py

```
def results(request):
    crop_data = cropInfo.objects.all()
    context = {
        'crop_data':crop_data,
    }
    ph = request.POST.get('pH')
    moist = request.POST.get('moisture')

    print(ph)
    print(moist)
    return render(request, 'results.html', {'ph':ph, 'moist':moist, 'crop_data':crop_data})
```

My urls and every other thing works fine but i am stuck in comparing those two values and showing the result on web-page.

This is my index.html

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="{% url 'results' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <label id="text" for="pH">pH</label>
       <input id="label" type="number" id="pH" name="pH" placeholder="Enter pH value" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <label id="text"  for="moisture">Moisture</label>
       <input id="label" type="number" id="moisture" name="moisture" placeholder="Enter moisture level" class="form-control" required>  
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
     <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style='float: left;' id="center" >Process</button>
     </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: probably because the posted ph and moist values are strings and the module values are not...?

Answer (score 0):

In views.py you are getting the inputed values from html page and printing on your terminal which is converting that number to a string. Your models.py should be either in char field or you should convert those values to interger type

```
moisture = models.CharField(max_length=100)
ph = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```